# Show HTML Text in TextBlock-Control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I try to get HTML-Text in a TextBock without HTML-Tags. DO anyone know, if it is possible to show html-Text in a TextBlock Control? Have I to use a WebBrowser Control for this case. I use simple HTML-Tags to format Text like Textalignment or Textdecorations.

Here is a example of my HTML-Text:

Headline for Testing

Descriptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try two different approaches:

1. Simply display the HTML content in a `WebBrowser` control. This has
   multiple disadvantages, such as not being able to be transparent,
   and its performance can be quite disappointing.
2. Convert your HTML content to
   **XAML FlowDocument**, which you can display natively in a TextBlock. You can find more information about how to convert
   [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/05/25/606317.aspx).